# My Arrow functioning in Subscription is not changing variable In Angular/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My Arrow function in subsctiption of observer not changing changing local variable bool

```
upVoteAvailability(i: number) {
    let bool!:boolean ;
    this.featureService.upVoteAvailable(i).subscribe(x=> {
      bool = x as boolean
      console.log(bool);//true
    })
    return bool//undefined
  }
```

Is there any other function of observer that changes variable?

Comment: Subscribe is asynchronous, so your function subscribes to the `upVoteAvailabe()` but before it obtains the answer it returns `bool`, which at that time is indeed `undefined`. Where do you want to use that bool variable, is it to make some HTML element disabled/enabled or something like that?

Comment: You can return bool inside subscribe function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subscribe function is asynchronous, this means when the `this.featureService.upVoteAvailable(i)` is called the code will not stop and wait for the Observable to return.

So in the end you need to wait for the Observable to return.

There are several ways to do so.

The easiest way is to use async/await.

```
async upVoteAvailability(i: number) {
    let bool!:boolean ;
    await this.featureService.upVoteAvailable(i).toPromise.then(x=> {
      bool = x as boolean
      console.log(bool);//true
    })
    return bool//true
  }
```

With async/await it is waited until the return value arrives. Async/await needs a Promise.